# Where does CiviCRM store Merge 'history'?

Tags: contacts, duplicate-contacts

After Merging Contacts -> dig up a Contact in the Trash bin and you'll see something like:

[image]

Where does CiviCRM store this information? How does it track which Contact is merged with which Contact?

Comment: I can see an activity in the merged record, but I doubt that's what CiviCRM is using here. I looked in all the tables like "%log%" to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An activity gets recorded when you merge and it looks up the target contact via that.

Use `$winnerContact = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'getmergedto', ['contact_id' => $contactId])`.

See also https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.20.2/api/v3/Contact.php#L1275

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much